# Passing a string from C# to the XAML button

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, button

This is a very simple question: I have a string defined in my C# class and I would like it to be the content of a XAML button. That's it. What can I put in the ????. I know this is basic WPF... I will keep looking for an answer. Thanks in advance.

My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="BarScore.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="Start" Content="???" Height="25" Width="100"
           Margin="20" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My C# code

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BarScore
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string BUTTON_NAME_STR = "START";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I know I can go to the code and write:

```
Start.Content = BUTTON_NAME_STR;
```

but I would like it to be from XAML to C# and not the other way around, if possible.

Comment: You have specified **Binding** as one of your tags. Didnt you get any simplest of example on internet of how data context is set and how binding works?

Comment: @AngelWPF I've found several examples but most were binding with resources (static and dynamic) others were binding with external xml. I've included binding since I though it might be a "binding" syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the binding to work, you will need to turn your field into a property like the following.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BarScore
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string _BUTTON_NAME_STR = "START";
        public string BUTTON_NAME_STR
        {
           get
           {
                return _BUTTON_NAME_STR;
           }
           set
           {
                _BUTTON_NAME_STR = value;
           }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Start.DataContext=this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then set your binding to your property

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="Start" Content="{Binding BUTTON_NAME_STR}"
       Height="25" Width="100"
       Margin="20" />
</StackPanel>
```

Some more links on it :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the effort and all of You that helped out. I was not being able to aggregate the different suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want something like:

```
<Button Name="Start" Content="{Binding BtnName}" />
```

but you may then *also* need to set the data context for the containing form/page/whatever.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it does not work. No errors are displayed but neither the button's content value, only a blank button.
Can you explain what you mean with "set the data context for the containing form/page/whatever"? I'm using a Window by the way. 
Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @Pimenta: I mean setting the `DataContext` property of the window to the object containing the data (which may be "this"). Alternatively you can specify a different binding root in the binding itself.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that was the missing link. @Redburn displayed the complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both @Jon Skeet and @Steve Greatrex's answers are valid, but I would like to explain them to @Pimenta.

Databinding in WPF is relative to a **Source**. You can

1. explicitly set this source on the Binding expression, as was the case in @Steve's answer (in his case it was a *relative source*);
2. or it can be implicit, as in @Jon's solution, in which case, the default source is the `DataContext` of the control, which could be set manually or inherited from its parent.

So, for @Steve's solution to work, what you refer to as your "C# code" should be the code behind for your xaml, which he assumes to be a window (the default item in WPF).

For @Jon's solution to work, you need to set the `DataContext` for your button. Either directly by writing:

```
Start.DataContext=this;
```

or by setting it (in code) for a control somewhere up in the xaml hierarchy.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `BtnName` property is on the parent `Window` you can use the following:

```
<Button Name="Start" Content="{Binding BtnName,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```